# FPT algorithm for dominating set

Tags: graphs

An instance of the Dominating Set problem is given by an undirected graph
$G = (V, E)$ and an integer $k$; it is a ‘yes’-instance if there is a subset of vertices $S ⊆ V$
with $|S| ≤ k$ such that for each $v ∈ V$ we have $v ∈ S$ or $u ∈ S$ for some ${u, v} ∈ E$.

I'm trying to show that if the degree of each vertex of $G$ is at most 3 then Dominating Set is in FPT with respect to $k$.

I thought of maybe creating a bounded search tree algorithm for this, where if all nodes have degree <= 2, it can trivially be solved in $O(|E|)$ time. Otherwise consider a node $v ∈ V$ with degree 3. Either it's in the dominating set, or one of its neighbours is which results in a $O(4^k |E|)$ algorithm. I think there should be something better (maybe using kernels?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the FPT algorithm in [Linear Time Algorithms for Finding a Dominating Set of Fixed Size in Degenerated Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4735). Since the proof applies for $k$-degenerate graphs, it also applies for graphs whose maximum degree is $k$.